# Pageddatasource fails paging With "does not implement ICollection."

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, datasource, paging

I've a Repeater and I need paging, so I'm using PagedDatasource.

Given:

```
string tag = Request.QueryString["category"];
```

and tag variable is NOT empty then PagedDataSource fails paging with the following error:

> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Cannot compute Count for
>   a data source that does not implement ICollection.

at this line:

```
lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " + pagedDS.PageCount.ToString();
```

NOTE: When tag variable IS empty then paging works fine.

Full code below:

```
string tag = Request.QueryString["category"];
var ba = new DataBase.BlogAdapter();

PagedDataSource pagedDS = new PagedDataSource();
pagedDS.AllowPaging = true;
pagedDS.PageSize = 3;

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tag))
{
    pagedDS.DataSource = ba.GetArticles(null, null);
}
else
{
    var t = new DataBase.Tag() { TagName = tag };
    var tec = new DataBase.TagEqualityComparer();
    pagedDS.DataSource = ba.GetArticles(null, null).Where(a => a.Tags.Contains(t, tec));
    CurrentPage = 0;
}

pagedDS.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;

// NEXT LINE FAILS IF "tag" IS NOT EMPTY
lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page: " + (CurrentPage + 1).ToString() + " of " + pagedDS.PageCount.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to materialise the filter as a collection, e.g.

```
ba.GetArticles(null, null).Where(a => a.Tags.Contains(t, tec)).ToList();
```

`IQueryable<>` only implements `IEnumerable`, whereas `IList<>` implements `ICollection`.

Comment: thanks. it works now. I still don't know why did it work without filtering and failed when it was filtered

Comment: @levanlevi - without filtering, the return of your ba.GetArticles() is presumably a concrete collection. However, as soon as you apply a *Where*, the return type is an *IQueryable* which has not yet been 'executed' (i.e. no ICollection properties like Count). PagedDataSource would have to iterate through the IEnumerable in order to count it, which it doesn't want to do FWR.